# how to copy Folders - FAKE F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-3.0, f#-fake, f#-fake-4

I am using  `Copy` function of FAKE to copy files from project1 to release folder ,I am using below code :

```
Target "CopyProject1" (fun _ ->
    !!(buildDir @@ "/_PublishWebsites/Project1/**/*.*")
        |> Copy releaseDir
)
```

to copy files from Project1 folder to release folder , then all files inside Project1 are being copied to release folder , but I want to maintain folder structure of Project1 inside my release folder , i.e. I want to copy folders of Project1 to release , Is this possible or I will have to create subfolders inside my release folders and copy one by one .and if there is no such way of doing this then is this possible using custom task?

If anyone can help in this regard , that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

That's available through [CopyWithSubfoldersTo](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-filehelper.html). It's description says that it:

> Copies several file groups, each represented by a FileIncludes object, to the target folder preserving the folder structure starting from the BaseDirectory of each FileIncludes.

The parameters are the same as Copy:

```
Target "CopyProject1" (fun _ ->
    [!!(buildDir @@ "/_PublishWebsites/Project1/**/*.*")]
        |> CopyWithSubfoldersTo releaseDir
)
```

**EDIT**

`CopyWithSubfoldersTo` works with `seq<FileInculdes>` while `!!` returns a single `FileIncludes`. This has to be converted to a single element list before it can be used.

Comment: @ Panagiotis : thank you for answer , I tried this code but it is throwing an error i.e. `FileIncludes is not compatible with seq<FileIncludes>`

Comment: Ooops, CopyWithSubfoldersTo expects a seq<FileIncludes> while `!!` returns a single [FileIncludes]. You can convert it to a single-element list, eg: `[!!(buildDir @@ "/_PublishWebsites/Project1/**/*.*")]`

Comment: yeah ...it' wroking ..ty 
Can we give base directory to this ?because it is creating folders from 
`build /_PublishWebsites/Project1/SubFolders` inside release , but i want subfolders of Project1

Answer (score 2):

I used `CopyDir` function of FAKE , and this is copying directories recursively , we just have to give the folder name and target location where we want to copy folders .Here is the code :

```
Target "CopyFoldersTargetLocation" (fun _ ->
    CopyDir targetDir SourceDir allFiles
)
```

Comment: The bad news is that this command completely flatens the folder structure into a single folder in the destination.

Answer (score 1):

Since others solutions did not work for my case, here is my homemade solution using basic .NET methods:

```
let rec copyFilesRecursively (source: DirectoryInfo) (target: DirectoryInfo) =
    source.GetDirectories()
    |> Seq.iter (fun dir -> copyFilesRecursively dir (target.CreateSubdirectory dir.Name))
    source.GetFiles()
    |> Seq.iter (fun file -> file.CopyTo(target.FullName @@ file.Name, true) |> ignore)

Target "CopyProject1" <| fun _ ->
    let source = buildDir @@ "/_PublishWebsites/Project1/"
    let target = releaseDir
    copyFilesRecursively (directoryInfo source) (directoryInfo target)
```